# translate product type title

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

```
     I am working on a drupal commerce site which needs to be multilingual.
```

The problem I am facing is that I cant translate the title field of product types. 
For example if I create a new product type called "Fruits" I want to be able to translate that title to other languages enabled on my site. I did replace the default title with a title field using the Title module but I still cant find my "Fruits" string to translate. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@redamakarem  You should use "entity translation" module for translate, After installing this module you have to find "Multilingual support" option in your product type called fruits.

Then you have to select "Enabled via Entity translation" option under multilingual support.then u have to translate your title field.Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use node to display the product since commerce doesnot provide a product display page.

Then by replacing the title for that content type allows you to translate the product title.

To create product node page while creating the product in commerce form you can make use of inline node form provided by using [Inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module